# Zsh moves texts when the prompt is too long

Tags: macos, zsh

Steps to reproduce:

1. Resize the terminal to width 80 or less, making it easier for prompt
   to wrap.
2. Temporarily rename `/etc/zshrc` in case it affects outcome. (Remember
   to change it back afterwards!)
3. Create a really deep folder, like

   ```
   mkdir -p /tmp/very-deep/directory/very-deep/directory/very-deep/directory/very-deep/directory/very-deep/directory
   ```
4. Run a clean Zsh with

   ```
   /usr/bin/env -i ZDOTDIR=/tmp TERM=xterm-256color /bin/zsh
   ```
5. Set prompt with `PROMPT='%~ '`.
6. Change directory to that folder. The prompt should wrap.
7. Try auto-complete. For example, type `dir` then hit Tab key.

On my machine, after the last step the `dir` was moved one character left. There was a space between prompt and command before I trigger the completion, which was eliminated by `dir` moving left. In other words, before I hit Tab the line ends with `directory dir`, but completion makes it `directorydir`. This behavior was similar to Bash not properly wrapping ANSI escape code with `\[` and `\]`, except that in this case there should be no ANSI escape code in prompt.

I tried eliminating all possible variables, including environment variable, configuration files, terminal emulator. What else can possibly go wrong?

In case it matters, I’m using Catalina.

Comment: Exactly the same happens to me (on 15.3) using either *Terminal.app* or *iTerm2.app* so it probably isn't your setup.

Comment: @lx07 thank you so much! Feel relieved to know that.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue on Ubuntu 18.04 Z shell 5.4.2 -- autocomplete works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Catalina 10.15.3 zsh is version `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)`.

Compiling version 5.7.1 from upstream [source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zsh/files/zsh/) shows the same error while version 5.8 does not.  As you can see below when setting `PROMPT='%~X` the `X` is deleted on pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> on `dir` in 5.7.1 but not 5.8.

[image: Screenshot]

The `NEWS` file supplied with 5.8 source says changes were made to completion functions which may explain this but in any case this bug appears to be fixed.

> ```
> Several changes have been made to the way completion functions track
> 'precommands' (such as `command` and `env`) and determine whether the
> command being completed for is a shell builtin. Developers of completion
> functions may wish to familiarise themselves with `_normal -p` and
> `_pick_variant -b`.
> ```

There is also this CVE included in version 5.8 so perhaps Apple will provide an update at some point if you don't wish to compile your own.

> ```
> CVE-2019-20044: When unsetting the PRIVILEGED option, the shell sets its
> effective user and group IDs to match their respective real IDs. On some
> platforms (including Linux and macOS, but not FreeBSD), when the RUID and
> EUID were both non-zero, it was possible to regain the shell's former
> privileges
> ```